# Import only the products from magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1.8

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, import, export, migration

I am creating a new site with Magento 2.1.8. I need to import only the products from an old site that is running on Magento 1.9. I want my old site to still be fuctional even after copying the product data. Please help!

Comment: I'm doing this now.
The process im using is exporting csv in mgnto1 & downloading sample data .cvs from mgnto2 then rearranging titles like the sample data if anyone has a simpler process let me know

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153906)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153906)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first take a backup of your current running 1.9 site's database. You can use migration tool , full guidance of migration process provided on this [link](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/).

This tool provide functionality for migration of products.

Comment: Bro, is possible can i use ver 1.9 database backup to my ver 2.x

Comment: @zus No its not possible

Answer (score 1):

Yeah but it's almost impossible to get the Magento Data Migration Tool working properly without loads of errors and without editing 10 or more core files... What's the point... how come WooCommerce makes it so easy and Magento complicates the hell out of it...
I gave up on the Migration tool and went for the Import option for customers, at least that's worked... Only the Product data seems to be an issue when trying to import, as usual with Magento. I see Magento 2 is still as rubbish at import/export as Magento 1 was.

Answer (score 0):

As you want only want to copy product from magento1 system,Then my suggestion,  export all product from magento1 using Default Data flow export or Export.

Then import then them to magento2 using  default import.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the example csv file for magento 2 has different attributes when compared to the exported csv file from Magento 1. Will it be compatible?

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended to use Official Magento Data Migration tool which will allow you migrate products, customer and more!

- Manual http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-tool-install.html
- GitHub https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool